# How can I prevent the user from navigating back to a previous page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, navigation

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, with three views: `view1`, `view2`, `view3`. The logic way for the user to navigate through these is: `view1` -> `view2` -> `view3`.

When the user reaches `view3`, then I must prevent them from loading `view2`, even by using the "Back" button in their browser.

What is a good, browser-independent means of implementing this?

Comment: @Shog9 - slightly different question.  The question you've linked is about stopping the 'click back, popup: this will resubmit your data'.

Comment: @russau: unfortunately, it's the same question asked for a different reason. I'll take a crack at editing this to differentiate though...

Comment: Ok - i've re-written this to reflect KentZhou's needs rather than his initial guess at how they might be implemented. As it stands, it's no longer a duplicate of the question i linked to, so i've removed that.

Answer (score 4):

In most of the applications you have to cope with the back ability from the browser. The user is used to it and he wants to use it and he more or less will hate pages that try to trick them when going back and forward.

Don't try to fool you user think about what he wanted to do and then try do deliver a not completely broken page.

Answer (score 2):

Add a check of referrer page on page load in your application and then show a page or redirect user back to used view. You cannot manipulate or disallow basic navigation on client, but you can solve this problem server-side

Comment: Thanks. Then what's the server side solution?

Comment: I'm not to good in ASP.NET, but php solution looked like:
<?php if (intval(substr($referrerpage,4)) > intval(substr($currentpage,4)) ) header("Location: http://".$URL."/".$referrerpage); ?>

Answer (score 1):

**I can't comment on the earlier posts, but note that some browsers don't pass referrers, and thus the earlier solution would break (throw an exception, actually).**

There are two steps to this:

1) You have to prevent browser-side caching. If you've got a three step process that the user walks through and it's dynamic, you're probably already doing this. If you don't prevent caching, the back button will show the cache of view1. Since step 2 is done server-side, the server won't have a chance to do anything.

2) You need to, as previous poster's have said, do something on the serverside to prevent the display. There are two ways to do this (despite my really bad pseudo code).

a) The quick & dirty way is based on the referer. For example, you'd put the following check on the controller for view2:

```
if (request.urlreferrer.absolutepath == "controllerview1")
{ //good }
else
{ //bad }
```

Also, in the case of "bad", you'll have to consider what to do. If you're using forms to pass values back and forth, you've suddenly lost when the user goes back to view2.

**Note, though, that some browsers don't ever pass referrers and the above check won't do any good (and request.urlrefferer will be null).** (I believe this is generally due to firewalls.) In which case you'd have to do:

b) I've done something like this before. The controller view1/2/3 is essentially a wizard where they're walking through the system. Each controller updates the db row associated with the wizard. So, view 2 would do something like:

```
if (dbrow.last_saved_page_num == 1)
{ // good }
else
{ // bad
  redirect("view" + dbrow.last_saved_page_num + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is outside of the scope of javascript, and cannot be disabled (though you can tell the browser to go forward or back, you cannot prevent it).  You would need a server side solution to disallow access to the pages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JavaScript solution, it would have to be implemented server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to view1 and view 2 that fires on page load, if you use jquery something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ window.history.forward(); });
```

or you could just just do this

```
<html onload="window.history.forward()">
```

Either way will do pretty much what you want, but maybe not be the best solution in terms of user experience - but if its all you have to work with then it might be the best solution.